# Producing content indefinitely in a separate thread for all connections?

Tags: python, twisted

I have a Twisted project which seeks to essentially rebroadcast collected data over TCP in JSON. I essentially have a USB library which I need to subscribe to and synchronously read in a while loop indefinitely like so:

```
while True:
    for line in usbDevice.streamData():
        data = MyBrandSpankingNewUSBDeviceData(line)
        # parse the data, convert to JSON
        output = convertDataToJSON(data)
        # broadcast the data
        ...
```

The problem, of course, is the `...`. Essentially, I need to start this process as soon as the server starts and end it when the server ends (`Protocol.doStart` and `Protocol.doStop`) and have it constantly running and broadcasting a `output` to every connected transport.

How can I do this in Twisted? Obviously, I'd need to have the while loop run in its own thread, but how can I "subscribe" clients to listen to output? It's also important that the USB data collection only be running once, as it could seriously mess things up to have it running more than once.

In a nutshell, here's my architecture:

1. Server has a USB hub which is streaming data *all the time.* Server is constantly subscribed to this USB hub and is constantly reading data.
2. Clients will come and go, connecting and disconnecting at will.

We want to send data to all connected clients whenever it is available. How can I do this in Twisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you probably want to do is try to extend the common protocol/transport independence.  Even though you need a thread with a long-running loop, you can hide this from the protocol.  The benefit is the same as usual: the protocol becomes easier to test, and if you ever manage to have a non-threaded implementation of reading the USB events, you can just change the transport without changing the protocol.

```
from threading import Thread

class USBThingy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, reactor, device, protocol):
        self._reactor = reactor
        self._device = device
        self._protocol = protocol

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for line in self._device.streamData():
                self._reactor.callFromThread(self._protocol.usbStreamLineReceived, line)
```

The use of `callFromThread` is part of what makes this solution usable.  It makes sure the `usbStreamLineReceived` method gets called in the reactor thread rather than in the thread that's reading from the USB device.  So from the perspective of that protocol object, there's nothing special going on with respect to threading: it just has its method called once in a while when there's some data to process.

Your protocol then just needs to implement `usbStreamLineReceived` somehow, and implement your other application-specific logic, like keeping a list of observers:

```
class SomeUSBProtocol(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []

    def usbStreamLineReceived(self, line):
        data = MyBrandSpankingNewUSBDeviceData(line)
        # broadcast the data
        for obs in self.observers[:]:
            obs(output)
```

And then observers can register themselves with an instance of this class and do whatever they want with the data:

```
class USBObserverThing(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.usbProto.observers.append(self.emit)

    def connectionLost(self):
        self.factory.usbProto.observers.remove(self.emit)

    def emit(self, output):
        # parse the data, convert to JSON
        output = convertDataToJSON(data)
        self.transport.write(output)
```

Hook it all together:

```
usbDevice = ...
usbProto = SomeUSBProtocol()
thingy = USBThingy(reactor, usbDevice, usbProto)
thingy.start()

factory = ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = USBObserverThing
factory.usbProto = usbProto
reactor.listenTCP(12345, factory)
reactor.run()
```

You can imagine a better observer register/unregister API (like one using actual methods instead of direct access to that list).  You could also imagine giving the `USBThingy` a method for shutting down so `SomeUSBProtocol` could control when it stops running (so your process will actually be able to exit).